# Uncrustify C function parameter in the presence of preprocessor directive

Tags: function, parameters, preprocessor, uncrustify

I have the following code snippet which is the output from a uncrustify execution, however the output is differnt from the expectation

Output:

```
extern void func1(short int a,
                  int       b,
                  int *c
#if defined (               NAME)
                  ,
                  int       d
#endif
                  );
```

Expectation:

```
extern void func1(short int a,
                  int       b,
                  int       *c
#if defined (NAME)
                  ,
                  int       d
#endif
                  );
```

Could you share which option and value would help me get the expected output